# Is there a way to update a complication directly from the iPhone app?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

I'd like to allow the user to be able to bypass the watch app altogether if possible.

I've tried importing ClockKit on my ViewController to create an instance of `CLKComplicationServer`. I get the "No such module" error.

Is there a way to communicate directly with the complication from the iOS app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CLKComplicationServer` is part of `ClockKit` that is available only watchOS2.

You can send data for complication from iOS using `[WCSession transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:]`. Not like `[WCSession transferUserInfo:]` It will awake watchOS App, and deliver your message as soon as possible.

It will awake your watchOS App, and call `-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)userInfo` of Watch side `WCSession`'s delegate. In this delegate, you can use `ComplicationServer` like this:

```
CLKComplicationServer* server = [CLKComplicationServer sharedInstance];
[server.activeComplications enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLKComplication * _Nonnull each, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [server reloadTimelineForComplication: each];
}];
```

finally it will invoke your `ComplicationController`.